# How do I add checkid_immediate support to a JanRain phpopenid example server?

Tags: php, openid, janrain

I'm using an OpenID server based on the JanRain phpopenid library. It's nothing special, simply patched to work with the Yubico onetime password generator. It authorizes fine, but fails the "Successful checkid_immediate" tests at the [JanRain diagnosis tool](http://openidenabled.com/resources/openid-test/diagnose-server/). It says a setup required for checkid_immediate, but I'm not sure what that means.

My problem is that the example demo JanRain came up with is purposefully spartan. According to JanRain's Jonathan Daugherty, "the example server is not supposed to be treated as a fully-equipped OpenID server (i.e., with user accounts and other state)."

Unfortunately, it's a bit over my head to figure out how to implement checkid_immediate on top of the watered down server example. Can anyone give me pointers about how one might achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the `checkid_setup` path and the `checkid_immediate` path is that you can't put any other intermediate pages in there where you prompt the user-agent for anything, you have to issue a response (probably either from `$request->answer(true)` or `$request->answer(false)`) immediately.